# Capitalize words in string except for ones in quote

Tags: python, string

I want to capitalize keywords in a list of strings except for keywords that are in quote.

let's say you have

```
list1 = ["I like bananas", "he likes 'bananas' and apples", "we like bananas and apples"]
list2 = ["bananas", "apples"]
```

the output I'd want is

```
>>> ["I like BANANAS", "he likes 'bananas' and APPLES", "we like BANANAS and APPLES"]
```

Comment: What about `"he said 'I like bananas and apples' and went away"`?

Comment: What about `"I like pineapples"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to check if the phrase in `list2` is surrounded by quotes or not:

```
import re

In [ ]: re.sub(rf"(?<!')\bbananas\b(?!')", "BANANAS", "I like bananas")
Out[ ]: 'I like BANANAS'

In [ ]: re.sub(rf"(?<!')\bbananas\b(?!')", "BANANAS", "I like 'bananas'")
Out[ ]: "I like 'bananas'"
```

You can create function to replace all patterns in `list2`:

```
def capitalize(s, pats):
     for pat in pats:
         s = re.sub(rf"(?<!')\b{pat}\b(?!')", pat.upper(), s)
     return s

In [ ]: [capitalize(s, list2) for s in list1]
Out[ ]:
['I like BANANAS',
 "he likes 'bananas' and APPLES",
 'we like BANANAS and APPLES']
```